# ffmpeg thumbnailer error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I'm trying get one thumbnail from a video in rails using gem carrierwave-video-thumbnailer but 
it is returning this error:

```
Check ffmpegthumbnailer install and verify video is not corrupt. Original error: No such file or directory - ffmpegthumbnailer
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, I re-install ffmpegthumbnailer and the bug is fixed. Probably something get wrong when I installed first time. Thank you all!

```
brew remove ffmpegthumbnailer
brew install ffmpegthumbnailer
```

Comment: i just installed it via brew install ffmpegthumbnailer command and it worked for me :)